# JQuery mobile + Phonegap : Ajax calls not working on Android Emulator

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a mobile web application built using the following versions :-

1. JQuery Mobile : Alpha 4 v1.0a4.1
2. JQuery: v1.6.1
3. PhoneGap : v0.9.5

Using phonegap, this application is built into a native android application and deployed.

In my application, i make various AJAX calls using $.ajax to external websites.
For this i employ dataType: 'jsonp' inorder to do the cross domain calling.

When i was testing my app in Chrome v12.0.742.100, everything was working fine and I had no issues with retrieving the data from the external sites. However, as soon as i packaged this into a .apk file and try to run this in the emulator, i find that none of the ajax calls are working.

I have put alerts before and after the ajax call and verified that both alerts are called but the ajax call is as good as ignored. I have logging in both the success callback and the error callback and neither is being reached. I have also verified by puting a breakpoint on the external server website (for my testing, i am just having a separate website on my local machine itself) and the server page is definitely not being called.

In logcat, the error that i can see is this :
**D/SntpClient(   59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol**

I am pretty new to phonegap as well as Jquery Mobile but as far as my understanding goes, my phonegap app file is referenced by **file:///** protocol whereas my AJAX URL is **http://127.0.0.1:someport/someapp/somepage** and the error seems to be indicating that these two dont mix!! If this is indeed the case, how do i go about make ajax calls from a phonegap deployed application?

Please feel free to point out anything else that may be helpful! I am pretty stumped at this point.

Edit : I have checked the AndroidManifest.xml file and all the permissions as per this [phonegap wiki link](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/30862722/phonegap-android-eclipse-quickstart) are set in this file.

Edit 2 : Adding in my client side code that intitiates the ajax call

```
var serverUrl = "http://localhost:2424/MyServer/RetrieveMasterData.aspx";
            $.ajax({
                url: serverUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: { MasterDataID: 1 },
                success: function(response) {
                        ...... business logic here
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        ...... error handling something here
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi, have you added the permission for connecting to the Internet?

Comment: I've no idea why it works on your chrome but not on ur android. But 1 thing i know for sure is that the same origin policy doesn't apply to file:/// protocol.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet that shows the issue.

Comment: @Paul - Updated the question with a code snippet of one of the ajax calls

Comment: I am facing with the same problem on Android 2.2 but in Android 2.3 it works fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android emulator does not recognize "localhost"...it should be 10.0.2.2 instead.
try changing the url to 
http://10.0.2.2:2424/MyServer/RetrieveMasterData.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Because the request is not in the same domain, and I solved the problem by adding `jqm config` that:

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
  // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!

  $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});
```

And this is a link: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Answer (score 0):

Another issue which occurs in Android 4.0+ (but not in older versions like 2.3)... is for ajax calls that require Basic Auth.  You have to manually set the Authorization header in `beforeSend`. You cannot use the new username: password: options added in jQuery 1.7.

The example below illustrates what you have to do.
Note: This requires the base64 jquery plugin.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "https://yoururl,
            type: method,
            dataType: 'json',
            // username: username,  // Doesn't work on ANDROID
            // password: password,  // Doesn't work on ANDROID
            beforeSend: function (xhr)
            {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + $.base64.encode( username + ":" + password ));
            },
            data: options.data,
            success: function(response) {

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I guess your code is for GET, but, what about POST ?, how to send data ?