# PhoneGap not issuing AJAX (jsonp) request

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I've been trying to battle this issue all day, and have googled all over the place. It may be that I just can't find that one page with the solution... but I have looked at problems and solutions such as:

[Ajax call on phonegap not sending request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110233/ajax-call-on-phonegap-not-sending-request)

[JQuery mobile + Phonegap : Ajax calls not working on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518278/jquery-mobile-phonegap-ajax-calls-not-working-on-android-emulator?rq=1)

and neither of the solutions there appeared to have resolved my issue.

All I want to do is issue an AJAX call to my remote server, upload a few parameters and download some content. This script works perfectly in a browser, but depending on minor changes to the file in Phonegap, either throws back a "timeout" error, or simply just says "error". The code is as follows (the AJAX endpoint is a dev endpoint, and I'll leave it up so you can try hitting it as well):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
<div id="app-status-ul">
<li>Loaded</li>
</div>
</ul>
</body>
<script>
var serverRegHit = function(data, httpStat){
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>Server Reg OK, HTTP status: '+httpStat+'</li>');
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>Data Status: '+JSON.stringify(data)+'</li>');
};
var serverRegFail = function(data, httpStat){
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>Server Reg FAIL, HTTP status: '+httpStat+'</li>');
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>Data Status: '+JSON.stringify(data)+'</li>');
};
      $.ajax({url:"http://keb.bz/gcm/?deviceid=12345",
              jsonp: 'callback',
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              timeout: 25000,
              success: serverRegHit,
              error: serverRegFail});

</script>
</html>
```

I have tried using cordova 2.9, and downgraded to 2.5, but this does not seem to have helped either.

My config.xml has whitelisted .* and the keb.bz domain, the permissions give the app access to the internet in the manifest - and I assume this works because it is able to successfully retrieve a GCM Device ID.

I have tried using JSON, JSONp, TEXT, and various dataType's through AJAX, but none of these have made any difference.

Is there another configuration point in Cordova/PhoneGap that I am missing?

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Any exception/error in the Logcat console? Are you sure the jQuery library is loaded successfully? First you should make sure pure JavaScript works, and then try to test if jQuery is ok.

Comment: JQuery loads fine because it successfully prints the error to the DOM, and could not notice anything exceptional in the log cat.

Comment: Make sure your app have "Network Access" permission.

Comment: Oh man - I can't believe I didn't add this properly in the manifest. Thanks for making me check again!

Comment: Did Network Access resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes it did, silly mistake on my part! Are you experiencing anything similar?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @xioawl for making me double check my manifest.xml. Turns out I had not correctly configured permissions there.

In the end, I wound up using Cordova 2.5, jQuery 1.10, (did not use jQuery Mobile), setting my res/config.xml with the following access paths:

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
<access origin="http://keb.bz" subdomains="true" />
<access origin=".*" />  <!-- only during development -->
```

Placing this snippet after including all JavaScript libraries:

```
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
   $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});
</script>
```

And using the following manifest.xml permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

My JSONp Query continues to look as follows:

```
$.ajax({url:"http://keb.bz/gcm/?deviceid=12345",
        jsonp: 'callback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 25000,
        success: serverRegHit,
        error: serverRegFail});
```

Hope this is useful to someone!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error today when i updated my app using online PhoneGap compiler...

i last complied the app in Apr 2015. 
Then did a few tweeks today ,   nothing major, complied it, and all my ajax request fell over. I did and alert of error strings and all it said "timeout".

i then specified the phonegap-version to 3.7.0, and re-compiled... all my ajax working again.
Not sure what CLI5.1 and 5.2 changed but it killed my app.

Short term solution, as soon 3.7 probably won't be supported anymore, and then i will be stuck for changes... good time to go native i guess

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I "solved" it by using crosswalk and downgrading chromium to version 42x. I don't feel good with this

Comment: @msander... no unfortunately not.