# Android Lollipop jsonp call works in debug but not release (Cordova)

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, jsonp

First of all, thanks to all the experts on this site. You've all gotten me through a lot!

I'm having an issue that I am just not able to figure out. In previous versions of Android (pre-Lollipop) I was able to make a jsonp call to my server through a Cordova app. Since 5.0+, I am getting the ReadyState:0 error. The really strange thing (at least to me) is that the code works just fine with a debug build, but doesn't in a release build. Here's the javascript/jquery:

```
var url = "https://mydomain.com/mobile/login.php?username=" + $('#username').val() + "&password=" + $('#password').val();

        if ($('#username').val() != '' && $('#password').val() != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#progressbar').fadeIn();
                    $('#progressbar').progressbar({value: false});
                },
                success: function(data){
                    if (!data.session){
                        $('#incorrect_login').fadeIn();
                        $('#progressbar').fadeOut();
                    } else {
                        localStorage.setItem("sessionId", data.session);
                        window.open("basepage.html", "_self");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

The server returns (if the username/password is correct):

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . "({'session': " . json_encode($sessionName) . "})";
```

The Cordova permissions:

```
<access origin="https://mydomain.com*" subdomains="true" />
```

And the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
```

I've followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333895/phonegap-not-issuing-ajax-jsonp-request) (amongst others):

I'm using Cordova 4.1.2, Cordova Android 3.6.4, and JQuery 1.10.2.

Thanks!

Comment: And you are using the same PHP server on both cases, right? And does your error callback (which is missing on your example, at least) get called when getting this error, if it does (as it probably should) what it does state as cause for the error?

Comment: I am using the same PHP server. The code for the error in the ajax call is this: `error: function(e){
         var error = JSON.stringify(e);
                        $("#incorrect_login").text(error).fadeIn();
     }`

Comment: Hit return too soon...

For whatever reason, the error isn't being reported. The progress bar is showing, so beforeSend is working. It's hard to completely troubleshoot since you can use developer tools with a release version. Is there another way to get the error message?

Comment: The error is: readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error".

Comment: the server certificate is valid? self signed? certification authority?

Comment: It is a PositiveSSL issued by COMODO RSA Domain Validation, and it is valid.